# API Gateway Auth with K8s Ingress + Python

Tags: python, authentication, kubernetes, architecture, api-gateway

Since [my previous Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64687757/5308802) about microservices cluster authentication, I got the following, more specific question. How can one implement API Gateway pattern in Kubernetes cluster to perform authentication with Python? So that any custom auth method can be used, and other microservices won't worry about this problem.

My requirement/wish list:

1. Use Python code to authenticate a request, to handle logging in&out.
2. Use K8s Ingress URL list or, at least, similar simple YAML interface, so that routing isn't embedded in a service code and can be rapidly updated.
3. The solution should have not the worst performance.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated

Comment: There is [example](https://github.com/dignajar/another-ldap-auth) on github with Docker image with a small script in Python for external authentication for k8s ingress. Could you check if this is what you are looking for? Additionally [there](https://tyk.io/docs/plugins/supported-languages/rich-plugins/python/custom-auth-python-tutorial/) is another example for tyk api gateway and [there](https://github.com/authelia/authelia) is a project authelia, which is authentication and authorization server providing 2-factor authentication and single sign-on, but it's based on go, instead of python.

Comment: @Jakub Thanks for the info! I also found this [article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-authenticate-users/) which explains the process and [an official repo](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth) with an example. I need more time to sort out and probably experiment with it. I'll let you know when I'll get some results `:)`

Comment: @Jakub the main apprehension I have is about supported auth protocols: in all these articles I see basic auth only, so I wanna check whether other methods are supported. And I'll appreciate if you can clarify this problem.

Comment: @Jakub I found [this repo](https://github.com/UnitedTraders/nginxauthdaemon) with another example of Python+LDAP+NginX, I think it's a good start, though I still have some doubts. And I found similar NginX module `ngx_http_auth_request_module` with even simpler auth protocol. Though the doc says all these modules aren't built by default into NginX, so I'm not sure my K8s Ingress support it... I also had a look on Tyk & Authelia, they seem pretty cool, but too complicated for now, I hope to solve the problem with pure NginX. Well, you can write an answer with all this info, I'll accept it `;)`

Comment: I'm glad it helped, I have combined all of our comments into short answer, feel free to add something if there is anything you want to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we mentioned in the comments.

---

NginX can deal with LDAP:

> There is [an article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-authenticate-users/) that explains the process and [an official repo](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth) with an example explaining Python+LDAP+NginX for external authentication for k8s ingress.

Also there is [a good unofficial example](https://github.com/dignajar/another-ldap-auth) of this technique.

---

The NginX module `ngx_http_auth_request_module` support even simpler protocol, and here is [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) and [an unofficial example](https://github.com/UnitedTraders/nginxauthdaemon).

---

Additional software can be used to solve the problem:

- [Tyk api gateway](https://tyk.io/docs/plugins/supported-languages/rich-plugins/python/custom-auth-python-tutorial/)
- [Authelia](https://github.com/authelia/authelia)